# Count percentage of audio samples exceeding a threshold

Tags: c, audio

I have this practice question that I have an answer to:

> In this stage of the project, you will identify any "danger" spots, in which the SPL is greater than or equal to 80
>   dB (the value above which long-term hearing damage is likely to result). The simplest approach is to logically
>   overlay a regular grid, and evaluate the SPL level at each point in the grid.
>   For this stage, assume that the plant in question is in a field of size 78  78 meters, with edges perfectly aligned
>   north-south and east-west.
>   Add further functions and loops to your program so that it evaluates the sound intensity at every whole-number-of-meters
>   grid point strictly within the field and on its boundaries (that is, at the points x 2 [0 : : : 78] y 2 [0 : : : 78],
>   and counts the percentage of those locations at which the sound intensity is above the 80 dB threshold that
>   indicates “risk of damage”.
>   Note that you need to be a bit careful, because if you happen to test the exact location of one of the sound sources,
>   a sound pressure level of infinity will be generated.
>    (Note: SPL is the sound pressure level)

The SPLtotal is already given and I have derived it in the previous stage.

```
printf("\nStage 3\n========\n");

/* count points with sound levels above danger limit */
danger = total = 0;
for(i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)      /* over length */
{
    target.y = i;
    for(j = 0; j <= SIZE; j++)  /* over width */
    {
        target.x = j;
        total++;
        if(spl_total(sources, count, target) > LIMIT)
            danger++;
    }
}
printf("Points sampled: %d\n", total);
printf("Above %.1f dB: %.1f%%\n", LIMIT, ((double)danger*100)/total);
```

I just want to see if the looping is done okay. Is this a good way to go or is there an alternative "cleaner method"?

Comment: Such title, much wow. 
What is `LIMIT`, `target`, `danger`? What does `spl_total()` return? This is incomplete code.

Comment: What is the "practice question" that you are solving?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please describe what the code is supposed to do and be sure to include all relevant code. As it stands, it is unclear what you're asking. Please see [How to get the most out of asking a question.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions)

Comment: [...] all the relevant code, *as well as a short description of what the code is doing* - the more context reviewers have, the more they are able to determine whether the *looping is done okay*, and to recommend alternatives.

Comment: Are you asking about the nested for-loop? There's nothing wrong with that generally. In your case, we really need to know more context to know whether or not a better option exists. I am sure there is something we can help you improve.

Comment: I'm not going to tell you your code is fine because you're leaving out a lot of context. I think the exercise has very little to do with actually writing code and more about standing waves in an enclosure and how to compute the areas that result in high SPL. That might involve integrating or some other mathematics that we cannot help you with here. Otherwise, as far as this forum is concerned you have written a program that has a nested for loop which is at least pointless to review.

Answer (score 4):

In C, the idiomatic way to iterate over an array of `SIZE` elements is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    …
}
```

The other way to write a loop that repeats `N` times is:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
{
    …
}
```

… but you wouldn't use that, since arrays in C are indexed starting from 0.

Mixing the two patterns, as you have done, is weird, and will likely lead to off-by-one errors when a future collaborator works on your code — if it isn't already a bug.

---

`total` could just be `(SIZE + 1) * (SIZE + 1)`.

---

Omitting optional braces is bad practice.  Think of it as an act contributing to a future [coding accident](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html).  If you don't like wasting two lines of vertical space for braces, then adopt the more compact K&R-style braces.  If you *really* want to omit braces for some reaons, then put the body on the same line as the test.

```
    if (spl_total(sources, count, target) > LIMIT) {
        danger++;
    }
```

or

```
    if (spl_total(sources, count, target) > LIMIT) danger++;
```